# Responsive Nav - Add a class if has children

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a nav for Desktop now on resizing the nav to a mobile / tablet screen size, I'd like to add a class of "dropdown" to the top level list item, If it has children. But I'd only like to do this for small screens i.e Tablet / Mobile. The desktop view of the nav is fine.

My HTML code is structured as follows :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="mobile">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Favourites</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dashboard">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="fitness">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Fitness</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stuart &amp; Elise</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Workouts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Fitness Plans</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Build my own plan</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Articles &amp; Videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="food">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Food &amp; Nutrition</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Faith Toogood</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Recipes</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Meal Plans</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Build my own plan</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Articles &amp; Videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="health">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Health &amp; Wellbeing</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dr Hilary Jones</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Emma kenny</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Journal</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Moodtracker</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Goal Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Articles &amp; Videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="community">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Community</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Groups</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stories</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Guests</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="help">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Help &amp; Info</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Quick start guides</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Logout</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap & LESS to build this.

How do I go about adding say a "chevron" or "accordion" class on a smaller device.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `:not(:only-child)` selector; to select `<a>` tags that aren't the only child of an `<li>` (i.e. the `<li>` has another child which is the dropdown), and use psuedo-element `:after` to add an arrow symbol.

```css
nav li > a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: '\00A0 \2193';
}

nav li:hover > a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: '\00A0 \2191';
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="mobile">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Favourites</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dashboard">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="fitness">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Fitness</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="food">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Food &amp; Nutrition</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Faith Toogood</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Meal Plans</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Build my own plan</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Articles &amp; Videos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="health">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Health &amp; Wellbeing</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dr Hilary Jones</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Emma kenny</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Journal</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Moodtracker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Goal Tracker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Articles &amp; Videos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="community">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Community</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Groups</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Stories</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Guests</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="help">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Help &amp; Info</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Quick start guides</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Logout</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```